# console to second display in windows

Tags: mfc, multiple-monitors, windows-console

I am writing an MFC-app for windows.
During development I am using a console window for debug output.
What I want is to set this console so that it shows up on second display as default on start.
Is it possible ??

Comment: Unless you have a striking reason to log to a console consider using [OutputDebugString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) instead.

Comment: @IInspectable, what is wrong to use a console to view Trace messages?  Is it a "poor man" tool? cmd is alltime everyhere on all window.

Comment: @tom A process can have at most one console attached to it. What do you do in a situation where that console is already used for something else? It's also somewhat complex to set up, and interferes with application logic that, at a later point, will try to attach to a console. Unlike `OutputDebugString` it also loses context relative to other diagnostic output. Also unlike `OutputDebugString` you cannot easily disable tracing output.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a handle to the monitor containing your app window:

```
HMONITOR hMyMonitor = ::MonitorFromWindow(MyHwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
```

Then you can enumerate all monitors using [EnumDisplayMonitors function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors)

In your [MONITORENUMPROC callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-monitorenumproc), compare its monitor handle to `hMyMonitor`. If it is different - you found another monitor. Now you can use [GetMonitorInfoW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow) to get [MONITORINFO structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-monitorinfo), containing

> rcWork
>
> A RECT structure that specifies the work area rectangle of the display monitor, expressed in virtual-screen coordinates.

Finally, you can get a handle to your console using [GetConsoleWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow), and move it anywhere you want with [MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow)

Comment: Thanks; but I got an another problem, Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019387/mfc-afxwin-inline-give-me-no-overloaded-function-takes-6-arguments

Comment: @enocknitti - looks like that other "problem" is solved? Is everything OK then?

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling I ended up with this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
    cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
    cfi.nFont = 0;
    cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;                   // Width of each character in the font
    cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 24;                  // Height
    cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
    cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas"); // Choose your font

    // Make a console window
    bool o = AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleOutputCP( CP_UTF8 );      // UTF-8 please

    // and a larger font so that I can read it :)
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), FALSE, &cfi );

    HWND hWConsol = GetConsoleWindow();
    ::MoveWindow( hWConsol, -800, 0, 800, 800, true );
#endif
```

Corrected code, works as charm :)   thanks !

Comment: This is ludicrous. You've invented a function whose sole purpose is to propagate arguments to an [already existing function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow). This adds noise for absolutely no purpose. Just call the function already.

Comment: Yes You are correct but it was my workaround for my missing  global namespace resolution prefix "::" I had totaly forgott about that one. :)