# MFC: _AFXWIN_INLINE give me "no overloaded function takes 6 arguments"

Tags: mfc, afx

In an MFC application I am trying to move a console window I have added for debug purposes.

```
    /*  Put here just for reference
        _AFXWIN_INLINE void CWnd::MoveWindow(LPCRECT lpRect, BOOL bRepaint)
        { MoveWindow(lpRect->left, lpRect->top, lpRect->right - lpRect->left,
        lpRect->bottom - lpRect->top, bRepaint); }
    */
        HANDLE hh;
        bool oo = CWnd::MoveWindow( hh, 100, 0, 300, 300, true );
```

I get this error:

```
Error   C2661   'CWnd::MoveWindow': no overloaded function takes 6 arguments    
G:\proj\repos\EnterDG\EnterDGDlg.cpp    201
```

The strange thing is that if I put the mouse pointer at the "MoveWindow"" I get the expected prototype. But if I use "goto definition" I get the definition you see in the first lines( greyed out ).

I have tried to "#undef _AFXWIN_INLINE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CWnd::MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#movewindow) has two overloads, one taking 5 arguments, the other taking 2 arguments. As the error indicates, there is no overload that takes 6 arguments.

It looks like you are trying to call the Windows API function [MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) instead. This is a free function, so you need to drop the `CWnd::` scope resolution. Using a global namespace resolution prefix is always safe, e.g.: `::MoveWindow(...);`.